# Clearing View Engines in MVC breaks sitemap breadcrumb styles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

In a MVC 5 web application that i am developing, for performance sake i am clearing the view engines and adding only the `RazorViewEngine` in `Global.asax.cs` using `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();` and it breaks the styles in the mvc sitemap breadcrumbs

***Before***

[image]

***After***

[image]

My sitemap partial view (SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml) looks like

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    @foreach (var node in Model)
    {
        if (node == Model.Last())
        {
            <li class="active">
                <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</strong>
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>
                @if (node.Title == "Home")
                {
                    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i></a>

                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                }
            </li>
        }
    }
</ol>
```

Somehow it appears to be falling back to another implementation than the partials under views > shared > display templates

What could be the cause?

**Edit**

I've missed some vital info here, another dev has done this at the bottom of the Application_Start()

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
{
     PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
     {
           "~/Areas/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
     }
});
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue on MVC 5 by calling `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();` followed by `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`. Please show the code you are using to repeat this. Note that the internal `MvcSiteMapProvider` view engine is for fallback when you don't have a template in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to see the output HTML - are the styles not being output to the HTML, or is the stylesheet broken?

Comment: works fine when ViewEngines are not cleared, i've also checked the rendered html it appears to be not using the partial when the ViewEngines are cleared as the html structure is different from the partial. no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks NightOwl and Rowan

The solution was to add `"~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"` as an item in  `PartialViewLocationFormats`

```
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
            {
                PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
                {
                    "~/Areas/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing an issue with the information you provided, but my guess is that you are not clearing and setting the view engines inside of the `Application_Start` method.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Note that the internal `MvcSiteMapProvider` engine is for backup when there are no views in your `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder. It will serve the default template from within the DLL in this case, which is what appears to be happening here.

That could happen if your Razor view engine is registered after the internal view engine. So, if you don't have this code in `Application_Start` (as you should), then you could try to insert the Razor view engine to ensure it is placed before the `MvcSiteMapProvider` fallback engine.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new RazorViewEngine());
```

Or as already mentioned, just remove the web page view engine in a single action.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.RemoveAt(0);
```

The internal view engine is registered the first time a `MvcSiteMapProvider` HTML helper is called. So if you are calling the add method after that point, you are adding the Razor view engine *after* the internal `MvcSiteMapProvider` view engine.

Comment: Thanks, i've located the problem in the Application_Start() see my edited question.

Comment: But the issue still remains, i have modified the ViewEngines.Add to    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
            {
                PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
                {
                    "~/Areas/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml"
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

When the `MvcSiteMapProvider` is loaded, it uses its own ViewEngine. I suspect you are removing it.

Try adding a new `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.MvcSiteMapProviderViewEngine()` object to the list of ViewEngines.

Comment: You might be right but, MvcSiteMapProviderViewEngine() is not available in the MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc. namespace.

Comment: Form the [source code](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Mvc/MvcSiteMapProviderViewEngine.cs) its an internal class, so not accessible

Comment: In that case, can you just remove only the ViewEngines that you don't want? Either that, or Reflection?